# What is the cost of event storage in substrate?

Tags: substrate, parity-io

While implementing my chain logic I was wondering whether to use events at all since they might cost the node extra storage for the event logs. What is the actual storage cost involved here? Do the logs get purged automatically at some point?

Comment: you need to be a lot more specific on SO

Comment: This kind of discussion should probably be made on a substrate specific forum.

Comment: This is the appropriate place to ask this question (with the `[substrate]` tag). You just need to remove other tags.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Runtime events are handled by the [System module](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v1.0/srml_system/struct.Module.html). Within your own module, you normally implement the default `deposit_event` function:

From the in-code documentation:

> `deposit_event`: Helper function for depositing an event. The default behavior is to call `deposit_event` from the [System module](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v1.0/srml_system/struct.Module.html). However, you can write your own implementation for events in your runtime. To use the default behavior, add `fn deposit_event<T>() = default;` to your `Module`.

If you look at the [System module code](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/srml/system/src/lib.rs), you will find that ultimately a helper function is called which stores the event:

```rust
/// Deposits an event into this block's event record adding this event
/// to the corresponding topic indexes.
///
/// This will update storage entries that correspond to the specified topics.
/// It is expected that light-clients could subscribe to this topics.

pub fn deposit_event_indexed(topics: &[T::Hash], event: T::Event) { ... }
```

This function modifies three storage items which you can find in the `decl_storage` for the System module:

```rust
/// Events deposited for the current block.
Events get(events): Vec<EventRecord<T::Event, T::Hash>>;

/// The number of events in the `Events<T>` list.
EventCount get(event_count): EventIndex;

/// Mapping between a topic (represented by T::Hash) and a vector of indexes
/// of events in the `<Events<T>>` list.
EventTopics get(event_topics): double_map hasher(blake2_256) (), blake2_256(T::Hash)
            => Vec<(T::BlockNumber, EventIndex)>;
```

The final part of the event story can be found in the `initialize` function in the System module, where all three of these items are "cleaned up":

```rust
pub fn initialize( ... ) {
    ...
    <Events<T>>::kill();
    EventCount::kill();
    <EventTopics<T>>::remove_prefix(&());
}
```

This `initialize` function is called in the [Executive module](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/srml/executive/src/lib.rs) at the beginning of every block, before `on_initialize` is called for any module:

```rust
fn initialize_block_impl(
    block_number: &System::BlockNumber,
    parent_hash: &System::Hash,
    extrinsics_root: &System::Hash,
    digest: &Digest<System::Hash>,
) {
    <system::Module<System>>::initialize(block_number, parent_hash, extrinsics_root, digest);
    <AllModules as OnInitialize<System::BlockNumber>>::on_initialize(*block_number);
}
```

In conclusion, the cost of adding a single Event in the runtime is:

- Running the `deposit_event_indexed` function.
- Adding a new item to two vectors in runtime storage.
- ... which are cleaned up at the beginning of the next block so the storage cost is not compounding.

Comment: Is this answer still valid today? Are events pruned after every block?

Answer (score 2):

Events are created the same as any other storage item and consume the same amount of storage, based on the type of the inner data being emitted.